# Can not get data with dictCursor on Amazon

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following code that works fine when I run it from my localhost, but it fails when I run it from Amazon. There is no differences in the code, its using the same database connection.

I use `pymysql` and I use dictCursor to fetch the data by column name. This is how I create the link:

```
self.link = self.db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

My problem is when I try to fetch the data. The following simple code snippet fails:

```
try:
    self.link.execute('SELECT * FROM crawler_data WHERE id="%d" LIMIT 1' % id_crawl);
    row = self.link.fetchone()

except pymysql.err.Error as ex:
    print "Can not fetch crawler data from database: %s" % ex

print "Before"

try: 
    if row["address"]:
        print "Filter Address: %s" % row["address"]
except Exception as ex:
    print "Could not filter the data: %s" % ex.message

print "After"
```

It does not even print "Filter Address". I guess that means that it fails on `if row["address"]:`. It does print both "Before" and "After".

I have also tried `row[u"address"]:` without any success.

When I print the `row`. I get the following data printed:
`{u'address': u'Ekhammargr\\xe4nd 7'}`

So questions:

1. My except is done, and it prints "Could not filter the data:". It does not print ex.message. How do I get the exception or error that is causing the `try` to fail?
2. I'm using the same code and the same database connection, fetching the same data. It works fine on my localhost Windows machine, but not on my Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk Linux App. How could this be?

**EDIT:**
I tried changing the if statement to:

```
if True:
    print "Filter Address"
```

It still failed on Amazon. If it was indentation error it should'nt work on localhost either... Any ideas?

Here is the complete function: http://pastebin.com/haJGFuj3

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, when I rewrote the code exactly the same, it started working. I was only using tabs as indentations and no spaces, I tripple checked and I didnt get any indentation error. So I'm not sure what could be causing these issues.

But when I rewrote the code from scratch, with same code. It worked.

**EDIT:** I was using Sublime Text 2 as editor and utf8 as encoding.